# spotlight does not find text in .docx files

Tags: macos, spotlight

On my MacBook Pro running Sierra I have this problem:  when I look for a text string in a MS Word ".docx" file the search function does not find it although it can be found all right when I save the same file as ".doc". 
What can I do to also find strings in .docx files?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. Do you have any version of Word installed? Also, please edit the body with your OS version. thank you

Answer (score 2):

There is a free Appstore app named Easyfind which enables you to set certain search parameters. When you open Easyfind you get the pane shown below.

[image]

Click on the Settings button in the top left corner and it opens the small additional pane on the left. You can set Easyfind to search files or folders or both and then using the small pane on the left you can click on one of the groups and be sure to add docx. After that just include your search phrase and hit the 
return key.

Comment: Sorry this does not help. Also with Easyfind, I see only the "doc" file but not the "docx" file with the test string!

Comment: did you add docx to the list of file types to search?

Comment: you might try .docx

Comment: Be sure to check the "file contents" under the "Search for" header.

Comment: Sorry, I have seen your comments only now. Yes, I did all as you suggest. For "doc" it works, for "docx" it doesn't. I am getting the impression there is some incompatibility inside the docx format (inserted control characters?) that prevent the search function from finding the string (no matter if it's via Easyfind or just from the "Search" field in the "Finder" window. Any suggestion will be welcome. For the time being the only way seems to be to use doc and not docx.